# Copying an image from another server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm developing a system that automatically applies watermarks to images stored on my server. I've got the whole watermark application part figured out, but I'm stuck on Facebook's API. I have been able to retrieve and display the logged in user's ID and the link works fine.. Here is my code:

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=467926826672494";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
}

function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
  'Image available at https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture?type=large';

});
}
</script>
```

Just so you are aware, "response.id" is the Facebook user's ID. I want to be able to automatically save the user's profile picture (from Facebook Graph) to a directory on my server. I can't seem to find any code that is compatible with the method I have used above.. I really appreciate the help and you will certainly be mentioned on my final page :)

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: `applies watermarks to images stored locally` This only works on images from the same host and same port and same protocol. If you want to modify an image that isn't from your website, you need to proxy it through your own site first, or just do the watermarking on the server end.

Comment: Seems that your are working with javascript in the user's browser, so it's going to be really difficult to do what you want (how are you going to connect to your server to save the file from the user computer in a secure way?).

I think that you should try to implement this in a server-side application with node.js for example if you want to do it in Javascript or with [PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0), Python,... but server side.

Comment: Everything is working on the server side, currently - the only user end script that is being executed is the file upload (manual version) and the Facebook login. I know it's possible, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: `This only works on images from the same host and same port and same protocol.` what i meant by locally, is the watermark is applied to images uploaded and temporarily stored on my server. It doesn't modify anything that isn't stored on my server. That's my problem. I need to save the profile picture from Facebook to my server so this process can be completed.

Comment: _“I need to save the profile picture from Facebook to my server”_ – well, then _retrieve_ that image server-side. It makes little sense to try and do that with (client-side) JavaScript, if the actual image manipulation happens on your server anyway.

Comment: How would I go about doing that @CBroe? Lol